# Make image which represents gradient of 4 colors

Tags: gradient

I like to write a function that gets 4 colors sitting in the corners of an image. The colors are 16 bit RGB. My job is now to output an 16x9 image that represents the gradient of these colors. The simplest case would be someone passes the color red for the topleft and bottomleft corner and green for the topright and bottomright corner. The image should now show the smooth transition from red to green :)  Which algorithms would you suggest ? Help is really appreciated :)

Comment: Have a look at color models http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_model Most color spaces provide a transition. There is no best or single solution; just pick what you like.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I need these operations.

createLinearGradient(horizontal)
createLinearGradient(vertical)
createLinearGradient(diagonal)
createBilinearGradient() there is a good picture about this in wikipedia

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation

But someone told me I could do everything with just one algorithmus